# Identifying and removing "NA"s and other errors

Tags: r, assignment-operator, na

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test for NA and select values based on result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488068/test-for-na-and-select-values-based-on-result)

Suppose you have a vector  -- you do a calculation on the vector -- many of the elements return "NA" -- how do you identify these "NA"s and change them to some usable integer

Comment: Language is R by the way

Comment: I do not think that selective extraction implies that selective assignment will succeed, so I am not voting to close.

Comment: The solution below is fine -- but of course you should be very very careful about this.  We're assuming that you've thought carefully about what "usable integer" is appropriate for your problem ...

Comment: I actually ended up converting various unuseable datapoints (non-responses) to NA then using the na.omit function to eliminate the rows containing NA before regressions -- thanks for introducing me to the .na type though.  Let me know if there is a neater way of dealing with unusable datapoints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your data is in `dat` (could be a vector, matrix, or data frame):

`dat[is.na(dat)]<-0`

replaces all `NA` entries of `dat` with `0`.