# How to not make dplyr mutate calculate for missing group

Tags: group-by, dplyr

I have data looking like this:

```
df=data.frame(a=1:6,b=rep(c("one","two"),each=3))
df[2,2]<-NA
```

I want to calculate the mean of each group for each row, like this:

```
df %>% group_by(b) %>% mutate(mean=mean(a))
```

The problem is that R views the NA as a group. Desired output would be

> mean=c(2,NA,2,5,5,5).

**Attempt**:

```
df %>% group_by(b) %>% mutate(mean=if_else(b==NA,NA,mean(a)))
```

but this throws an error

Comment: You can't test for `NA` values using `==`, because `NA`s propagate. `1==NA` is `NA`! Use `is.na`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test for NA and select values based on result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488068/test-for-na-and-select-values-based-on-result)

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry! Didn't find that... kind of hard to know what to search for =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df %>% group_by(b) %>% mutate(mean=mean(a)) %>% mutate(mean = if_else(is.na(b), NA_real_, mean))
```

Comment: Yes, tried that myself just now, it works! Thanks for helping! Would you happen to know why this works and not my attempt?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid error messages:

```
library(hablar)

df %>% 
  convert(chr(b)) %>% 
  group_by(b) %>% 
  mutate(mean = if_else_(!is.na(b), mean(a), NA))
```